# data retrieval through another application from parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

Am working with **Parse.com** from Android studio. I have one question that i added in parse table through one android application.

Can I access the same data from another application from other device? if yes then tell me the solution ,i tried a lot but i can not do this thing.

My code for getting data

```html
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GPsLocation");
                query.fromLocalDatastore();
                query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            // retrieved the object
                            String s = parseObject.getString("latitude");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // failed lookup. Do something here
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception Thrown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

the image of my parse class is [image: Image of class GPsLocation]

Comment: you must remove `query.fromLocalDatastore();` if you want to access data from the server? Otherwise you query directly on the device, and if you have not pinned "GPsLocation" data on the device before, it will come up empty

Comment: Sir how to pin data on device ?

Comment: Sir I have two different apps. one is putting data in GPSLocation Table and other android app is retrieving data from android app

Comment: Simply remove `query.fromLocalDatastore();` and it should work. No need to pin the data locally if you want to share the data between devices (cause then you need to look up online anyway)

Comment: Sir I simply tell my requirements. I am putting data in GPSLocation table on parse.com. I have android app GPS which is saving data in GPSLocation table.Then I create the another app LocationReciever and try to get the data added by GPS app.And I provide the same KEYS to both apps which leads to same table. but I am not getting data through LocationReceiver App

Comment: Well, I cannot see why the code you provided should not work, besides removing the `fromLocalDatastore()` as already mentioned. Maybe `getQuery("GPsLocation")` should be `getQuery("GPSLocation")`? looks like a typo. Otherwise please post the code you use to upload a location

Comment: By the way, in case you missed it. Parse has a special GeoPoint object type, which enables geospatial queries: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#geopoints

Comment: @ cYrixmorten I posted my uploading code in my answer please check it and help me for that

Comment: You could just edit your answer but ok :p .. I cannot see any reason for that not to work .. what is in the toast message you get? I suppose it prints  "Exception Thrown"? .. if so please try to log or make a toast with `e.getMessage()`

Comment: it states that "no result found for query" and bro please help me i am stuck very badly

Comment: Can see from you screen that something is wrong with the ACL .. they are not saved as public read/write for some reason. Think that is the problem. Though I can see you set defaultACL to be public

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have spottet ACL to probably be the cause of your issue, try to change:

```
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        // Optionally enable public read access.
        // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
        // Add your initialization code here
        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
```

To:

```
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        // Optionally enable public read access.
        // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
        // Add your initialization code here
        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
```

Not sure if the canges to the `defaultACL` are having any effect if not done before calling `ParseACL.setDefaultACL()`